# Ordinal encoder with column transformer changing column index after executing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encoding, ordinal, data-transform

I am using ordinal encoder to convert categorical variables in to numeric for one of my dataframe.
as i am using ordinal encoder in column transformer and fitting my pipeline.
My columns index are getting shuffled.

## `imputer transformer`

```
imputer_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
            ('imputer_1',SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'),[0,16]),
            ('imputer_2',SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),[4]),
            ('imputer_3',SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='Other'),[13])
        ],remainder='passthrough')
```

## encoding transformer

```
transformer_1 = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('ord_encoder',OrdinalEncoder(),[0])]
       ,remainder='passthrough')
```

## `standard scaling transformer`

```
transformer_2 = ColumnTransformer([
        ('scaling',StandardScaler(),slice(0,44))])

pipe=make_pipeline(imputer_transformer,transformer_1)

new_df=pd.DataFrame(data=pipe.fit_transform(X_train_os))
```

--on running above code, i got

[Dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OazZV.png)

My original dataframe was-

[dataframe before encoding and pipeline fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lc3T.png)